# Was Christ referring to a particular sin in Matthew 7:3?

Tags: matthew, christology, gospels

Matthew 7:3 ESV

> 3 ***Why do you see the speck that is in your brother's eye, but do not notice the log that is in your own eye***? 4 Or how can you say to your brother, ‘Let me take the speck out of your eye,’ when there is the log in your own eye?

Christ speaks of a speck in your brothers eye and warns one to remove a log in ones eye before attempting to remove it from your brother"s eye

In the above text was Christ warning one never to try rebuke a brother whilst doing the same particular sin or just any other sin.

Was Christ warning about a particular sin or just general sins.

Answer (score 2):

**Was Christ referring to a particular sin in Matthew 7:3?**

No, Jesus was not referring to any particular sin, he was pointing to our ability to judge our brothers properly.   We are all imperfect, and should not overreact,  to rush and help a  brother to remove a minor flaw a "speck"  from his figurative spiritual vision so that it will help him judge properly, when ours is impaired by a log.

To illustrate this;

A blind man from birth was healed by Jesus on the Sabbath, he was then brought to the Pharisees for questioning,  he replied:

John 9:30-34 NASB

> 30 The man answered and said to them, “Well, here is the amazing
> thing, that you do not know where He is from, and yet He opened my
> eyes! 31 We know that God does not listen to sinners; but if someone
> is [a]God-fearing and does His will, He listens to him. 32 [b]Since
> the beginning of time it has never been heard that anyone opened the
> eyes of a person born blind. 33 If this man were not from God, He
> could do nothing.”

The Pharisees retorted.[ Vs 34]

> 34 They answered him, “You were born entirely in sins, and yet you are
> teaching us?” So they [c]put him out.

The Pharisees  with a log in their eye were totally blind and thus not able to judge matters  properly, Jesus replied [Vs 7:5]

> 5 You hypocrite, first take the log out of your own eye, and then you
> will see clearly to take the [f]speck out of your brother’s eye!

Answer (score 1):

Sin? Jesus wasn’t talking about ‘sin’. He was talking about Judging - *judging yourself*. And that *certainly* is *not* (a) sin. The *context* is clear. We see it in the previous verse.

**MAT 7:1** *Do not judge, or you too will be judged. 2 For in the same way you judge others, you will be judged, and with the measure you use, it will be measured to you.*

I appreciate some may want to argue whether ‘judging’ others *is* a sin or not, and then ‘add’ that context *into* this passage - but the fact is that is *not* the focus or point of what Jesus was saying.

On other occasions, Jesus told people to judge (Luke 12:57 and John 7:24). The disciples told people to judge (Acts 4:19; Romans 14:13; 1 Corinthians 5:12, 6:2, 10:15, 11:13, and 14:29). Paul judged (1 Corinthians 5:3 and 2 Corinthians 5:14). There are many examples of people judging. Paul prayed that our love would abound more and more in all judgment (Philippians 1:9).

In the light of these scriptures, it is evident that there must be a right and wrong type of judging - and *that* is the focus of this passage - it’s *not* about ‘sin’.

It is the condemning, or rather pointing out the type of judgment that is wrong. Also notice that in these scriptures, Jesus was not forbidding judgment; He was warning us to be careful with our judgments because we will be judged accordingly.

This same principle is stated in Romans 2:1-3 and James 2:12-13. There are certain cases where we have to pass a condemning sentence, as Paul did (1 Corinthians 5:3-5 and 1 Timothy 1:20). This warning constrains us to be certain that we ‘judge’ *righteously*, and are not simply venting our own frustrations.

Answer (score 1):

Luke 6,38 makes a very relevant and meaningful comment in all this serious business of judging.

"For the same measure that you use, it will be measured back to you. This precept underlies Shakespeare's play Measure for Measure both in its title and its eschatological plot has become one of the best known passage of the sermon. Compassion for others should give us reason not to sit in judgement of our fellow humans. We are all bound together in this life. Rather than judge let us seek the Lord's counsel - "Give and it will be given unto you; good measure , pressed down, shaken together and running over will be put into your bosom." Luke 6;38.

Comment: Welcome to BH and thanks for your answer. Everything you say I'm sure is true but I'm having difficulty seeing how either of your answers directly answers a specific aspect of Matt 7:3. e,g. if you do not quote any of Matt 7:3 then we are left to make the link between Matt 7:3 and your answer. Could you edit to help me make that link please?

Answer (score 0):

Christ was Speaking about, The passing of Judgment
And with Christs Words we see the emphasis of Maturity as a a requirement for Sound Judgement.

This the Apostle Paul expounds more here.
Gal 6:1 BSB Brothers, if someone is caught in a trespass, you who are spiritual should restore him with a spirit of gentleness. But watch yourself, or you also may be tempted.

Here the context is not of Sins wether in general or in particular

Comment: So, what is the context here?

Comment: Passing of Judgement. Mat 7:1-5

Comment: in general or in particular of the passing of judgment?

Comment: Passing of Judgement lifts it's self above the general or individual picture.  It's wholistic.   When someone is in the wrong or Sins, One must be Spiritually Mature as is the proper grounds for passing judgement on another.  Not necessarily that he must or must have sinned that particular sin.

Comment: Can a spiritually matured person sin?

Comment: I do not see how your questions relates to my answer to the post

Comment: Answer the question. Then you'll see :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130519/discussion-between-faith-mendel-and-tony-chan).

Comment: Better yet, please join https://www.facebook.com/groups/129702255041932.  We are there for you :)

Comment: I did join.  Didn't see any thing related to our discussion. So I'll have to leave the group

Comment: I just messaged you. Thanks :) BTW, so far, I have not said anything that contradicts you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a particular sin. The warning here is for **hypocrisy**, which God takes a hard stance on.

Proverbs 11:1 (KJV):

> A false balance is **abomination to the Lord**: but a just weight is his
> delight.

Luke 12:1

> In the mean time, when there were gathered together an innumerable multitude of people, insomuch that they trode one upon another, he began to say unto his disciples first of all, **Beware** ye of **the leaven of the Pharisees, which is hypocrisy.**

Answer (score 0):

### Luke's Version Gives a Clearer Perspective

In both Matthew and Luke, the saying comes as the conclusion Jesus' most notable sermon (on the Mount in Matthew, on the Plain in Luke). As pertains to the text in Matthew, I agree with the previous answers that Jesus speaks in general terms about the sin of hypocrisy. However, it is instructive to compare the context in Matthew to Luke's version:

In Matthew (6:25-34) the context is the idea that one should "consider the lilies of the field" and rely sole on God:

> Therefore do not be anxious about tomorrow, for tomorrow will be
> anxious for itself. Let the day’s own trouble be sufficient for the
> day. (6:34)

This doesn't give us much to go on, in terms of a specific issue. But in Luke, the saying comes shortly after the teaching on loving one's enemy and being merciful as God is merciful (Lk. 6:27-36).

> Love your enemies, and do good, and lend, expecting nothing in return;
> and your reward will be great, and you will be sons of the Most High;
> for he is kind to the ungrateful and the selfish. 36 Be merciful, even
> as your Father is merciful.

**Conclusion: in Matthew's version, the teaching about the speck and the log relates to hypocrisy in general, in the context of not worrying about tomorrow but relying solely on God. In Luke's version, however, we get a more definite sense of the sins Jesus is worried about: disobeying the command to love one's enemy and to be merciful as God is.**

Answer (score 0):

I've always taken as a rather wonderful example, the Lord's words to the Woman taken in adultery, recorded in St John's Gospel. John 8, 1-11.

Jesus answered the accusers of the Woman with these words. "He who is without sin among you let him be the first to throw a stone at her."...And when they heard it, they began to go out one by one, beginning with the older ones, and he was left alone, and the woman where she had been, in the midst.

"Woman where are they? Did no one condemn you?"

And she said, No one, Lord."

And Jesus said, Neither do I condemn you; go you way; from now on, sin no more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a second "answer". Did you mean to add information to your first "answer", if so use the **edit** feature under it to do so.